# Graph Api call with filter query

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph, typescript

How can I filter the API call dynamically passing through variable?

I am getting value in this variable through another API call:

```
var userid;

 this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient().then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
  client
    .api('users')
    .filter('identities/any(c:c/id eq '+ userid)
```

In the console I am getting this value in the filter query, instead I am not getting value of the variable "userid".

[image]

In the render function, storing the value of variable userid.

Making variable userid global by writing simply var userid; at the top where we import the library.

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactTaskProps> {

 return (
  <div className="cal" >
    
        {this.state.events.map((item, key) =>
       {if(item.percentComplete != 100){
        var tablerow = $("<tr>");

        tablerow.append($('<td>').append("<a href=" +"https://tasks.office.com/credentinfotech.com/en-GB/Home/Planner#/plantaskboard?planId=" + item.planId + "&taskId=" + item.id + " target='_blank' >" + item.title ))
        tablerow.append($('<td>').append((() => {
          switch (item.percentComplete) {
            case 0: return "Not-Started"
            case 50: return "In-Progress";
          }
        })()))
        tablerow.append($('<td>').append(moment(item.startDateTime).format('MM/DD/YYYY ')));
        tablerow.append($('<td>').append(moment(item.dueDateTime).format('MM/DD/YYYY')));
       

 //here I am storing the value in the variable userid

      userid = item.createdBy.user.id;
        console.log(userid);
          
        tablerow.append($('<td>').append(profilename))
       
      $("#tbody").append(tablerow);
    
          
       }}
       )
      }      
  </table>  
        
  </div>
  </div>
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Try below solution. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
.filter(`identities/any(c:c/id eq ${userid}`)
```

Make sure first part is correct.

**Reference**: [Consume the Microsoft Graph in the SharePoint Framework - Using MSGraphClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial#using-msgraphclient)

---

You can also use it like:

```
let filterString = "identities/any(c:c/id eq " + userid;

this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient().then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
  client
    .api('users')
    .filter(filterString)
```

Comment: @abhishek Have you tried this? is it working for you?

Comment: I have used both the way but i am not getting the varaiable userid value in the filter query

Comment: You have defined `var userid;` just before API call. I can see that you are not assigning any value to this variable....try adding some static value first and then check value of `filterString` before API call using `console.log(filterString);`

Comment: filter query is working by adding static value to the variable userid , but  why i am not getting dynamic value to global variable userid

Comment: So, that is different issue. it is based on how/when you are setting value of userid variable. If you are calling API before setting the value of userid, you will not be able to access its value. Make sure first you are setting the variable value and then you are accessing it (by calling API). Also, if you are creating a global variable, you should not write `var userid;` again before API call.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of filtering the api i have used api like that**

```
.api('users/'+`${userid}`)
```

**Declaring userid as a global variable with dynamic id**